# Binding a ListView to an ObservableCollection of ArrayList items without named properties

Tags: c#, listview, arraylist, observablecollection

Firstly:

```
        <ListView Height="259" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,6,0,0" Name="dataListView" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="899">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="240" Header="Test" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="Result" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Column 3" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

is the definition in my XAML file.

Then when a test starts, I run:

```
dataListView.ItemsSource = tr.TestResultCollection;
```

In TestRunner.cs, I have created the Observable Collection of ArrayLists as such:

```
ObservableCollection<ArrayList> _testResultCollection = new ObservableCollection<ArrayList>();
```

and publicly refer to them as such:

```
        public ObservableCollection<ArrayList> TestResultCollection
        { get { return _testResultCollection; } }
```

Finally when I add to the collection, I use :

```
_testResultCollection.Add(SummaryVerificationTestCase1(dbs, dbd));
```

which adds an ArrayList to the collection.  (Yes, a collection of ArrayLists, I know...)

However, what gets displayed in each Column is (Collection), (Collection, (Collection).

I see why.  However, I'm not entirely certain what the neatest way around is.  Normally in each GridViewColumn you give a binding like:

> DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TestResult}"

But the ArrayList doesn't have named components, just indices (0-2).

Is there a way to bind each column to the individual indices? Or have I missed something simple already?

Comment: `ArrayList` is the most useless list in the .NET Framework. Please use arrays or `List<T>`. Your sanity will thank you.

Comment: It's mainly as I'm using others' legacy code structures.  I am considering restructuring ;)  Thanks though.

Comment: and after that comment, I spent an hour reworking it all. Much better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify an index in the binding path:

```
       <GridViewColumn Width="240" Header="Test" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=[0]}"/>
       <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="Result" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=[1]}"/>
       <GridViewColumn Header="Column 3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=[2]}"/>
```

Comment: gah, it was that simple. Perfect!